# coercing a function into character for plot() main title in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to make a `main` title for my `plot()` based on the two arguments of the function (*see `if` statement*). Specifically, I want anything that is used in front of `FUN` or `hold.at` exactly appears in the `main` title.

For example, below I want the `main` title be the word `mean`, but my trials have not been a success.

Can this be achieved in R?

```
main.title <- function(FUN = mean, hold.at = NA){

main <- if(is.na(hold.at)) mean else hold.at 

plot(1, main = paste0("held at: ", main)) 
}
# Example:
main.title()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `deparse` the `FUN`

```
main.title <- function(FUN = mean, hold.at = NA){
     v1 = deparse(substitute(FUN))
     main <- if(is.na(hold.at)) v1 else hold.at 

     plot(1, main = paste0("held at: ", main)) 
}


main.title()
```

[image]

```
main.title(hold.at = "Other")
```

Comment: @akrun Can you please help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345578/how-to-decide-threshold-value-for-selecting-features